# Element view is getting not tapped in robot framework with appium

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I am using robot framework with appium library.
My xpath is correct and its correctly finding the element but it is not tapping on it. When I ran appium ide I found that colored selector are not on actual element.

[image]

After entering xpath for this radio button, Element is found correctly but using same element with "Click on element" is doing nothing. You can see selection color (blue) is slightly downwards and there is not element.

Comment: Please double check sometime it's duplicated. you can use keyword Xpath "Should Match X Times" to test .

Comment: Can you show example? Or link?

Comment: example  ${count}= Get Matching Xpath Count  ${YOURXPATH} . then see the log how many xpath.